# how to average first n numbers in ms excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have two columns in an Excel spreadsheet that look like:-

```
Key Values
f   1
f   2
u   3
g   4
g   5
h   6
h   7
j   8
j   9
k   10
k   11
k   12
```

I want to create apply formula which creates an average of first n numbers in ms excel.

I Try this:-

=AVERAGE(B:B,10)

but could not get the answer.

Please help me for give me appropriate answer.

Comment: @JvdV Yes , I want to search for the average of first `10` numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid *volatile* set-ups with `OFFSET` or `INDIRECT` where possible:

`=AVERAGE(B2:INDEX(B:B,n+1))`

Or, as pointed out by @**JvdV**:

`=AVERAGE(TAKE(B:B,n+1))`

Replace *n* as desired.

Comment: @JvdV but sir i use version 2007, so in that `=take()` is not there.

Comment: @KUMAR But `AVERAGE` and `INDEX` most certainly are!

Comment: Sir please explain me the first one fourmula, It Works.

Comment: Sir please explain the fourmula so that me & future readers also understand.

Comment: `INDEX` can return a *reference* as well as a *value*. So, assuming *n* is 10, for example, the part `INDEX(B:B,n+1)`, which is `INDEX(B:B,11)`, will resolve to the *reference* `B11`, which means that `=AVERAGE(B2:INDEX(B:B,n+1))` becomes `=AVERAGE(B2:B11)`.

Answer (score 0):

in cell E1: enter the number of rows to take into account for average

in cell F1: enter ="B1:B"&E1

in cell E4: enter =AVERAGE(INDIRECT(F1))

Rgds
Frederik